DB Schema Design to Support Custom Application Flows & Logs
I'm working on a Database Schema Design, where custom fields can be added in the future. I'd like to figure out the following:

If adding columns to the existing table as per requirement is good or maintaining a separate table to identify the attributes is good. (Adding columns would be a costly operation as the table data is huge)

Example:
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS customerKyc(
user_id INTEGER,
pan VARCHAR(10),
is_pan_verified BOOLEAN,
pan_verification_id INTEGER,
created_at TIMESTAMPTZ,
updated_at TIMESTAMPTZ,
deleted_at TIMESTAMPTZ,
PRIMARY KEY(user_id),
UNIQUE(pan)
);

Now we have a business requirement to add GSTIN and also store whether its verified or not. Instead of adding GSTIN to the above table, I thought of the following solution for all future additions.
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS appUsers(
user_id INTEGER,
full_name VARCHAR(60),
is_kyc_verified BOOLEAN,
created_at TIMESTAMPTZ,
updated_at TIMESTAMPTZ,
deleted_at TIMESTAMPTZ,
PRIMARY KEY(user_id)
)

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS customerKyc(
doc_id INTEGER,
user_id INTEGER,
doc_name VARCHAR(20),
doc_value VARCHAR(20),
is_verified BOOLEAN,
verification_id INTEGER,
created_at TIMESTAMPTZ,
updated_at TIMESTAMPTZ,
PRIMARY KEY(doc_id),
FOREIGN KEY(user_id) REFERENCES appUsers(user_id)
FOREIGN KEY(verification_id)
);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS verification_details(
verification_id INTEGER,
verification_mode VARCHAR(20),
verification_timestamp TIMESTAMPTZ,
PRIMARY KEY(verification_id)
);

In this approach, I could enter the doc_name as "PAN", "GSTIN" and accommodate any other future requirements for the specific user role. Is this the best approach possible?

What is a good approach to store logs for the above table if we would like to show the log history?

If any other information is required, would be happy to provide.
